# No video output when copying a video frame by frame

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I want to superimpose some sensor information (time series) on a video file. I figured Python and OpenCV would be a nice way and started learning the basics, so I decided to make the simplest toy example I could think of: load the video and copy it frame by frame.

This is my code:

```
import cv2

src = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')
if not src.isOpened():
    print("Error opening src")
    quit()

width = int(src.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(src.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps = src.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)

fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')
dest = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, fps, (height, width))
if not dest.isOpened():
    print("Error opening dest")
    quit()

ret, frame = src.read()
while ret:
    dest.write(frame)
    ret, frame = src.read()

dest.release()
src.release()
```

- **Expected**: An exact copy of `input.mp4` as a XviD file in `output.avi`
- **Observed**: `output.avi` is a 5.6 KB file which apparently only contains an AVI header. It can't be reproduced by `mplayer` and neither can it be read with `cv2.VideoCapture`.

These are my settings:

- Debian GNU/Linux 9
- Python 2.7.13
- `cv.__version__` returns '2.4.9.1'
- FFmpeg 3.2.5-1

For reproducibility, here's a command line to download a very short YouTube video with `youtube-dl`:

```
youtube-dl 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfkcI8dhfsQ' -o input.mp4
```

Comment: Does the `read` ever actually succeed?

Comment: I think so. The loop is executed 51 times. (For the sample YouTube video I listed in my question.)

Comment: I have now read suggestions that Open CV 2x is incompatible with FFmpeg 3x, but I don't know how to confirm if this is relevant to my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line it should be `(width,height)` not `(height, width)`:

```
dest = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, fps, (height, width))
```

VideoWriter has to have the same size as the frame you are writing otherwise it doesn't work right.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I got myself fooled by `frame.shape()` returning `(height,width,depth)`.

Comment: @giusti Yeah I don't know why they do that height,width anyway. It's just going to confuse people.